# vector and iterators

Tags: c++, iterator, std

I have a vector that defined like below

```
vector<Field> m_vField;
```

I fill the vector by this command:

```
 AddFiled(const Field& aiField)
 {
   m_vField.push_back(aiField);
 }
```

But when I try to run iterator the vector this crashed after first iteration by "Access violation reading location"

```
vector<Field>::iterator it;
for(it = m_vField.begin(); it != m_vField.end() ; it++)
{
   dosomthing
}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: The code you posted is OK. Chances are the error is in "dosomthing". Please post more code.

Comment: you have two names for your vector in the code you posted (m_vField and vField) - cut/paste error? Also please show how you use the iterator.

Comment: Does `dosomthing` modify `it`, or add or remove elements from the vector? The code you've posted won't cause an access violation.

Comment: Is the vector declared inside a class or something?? Just a doubt as you have written a separate function to push into the vector when you can do it directly also.

Comment: In dosomthing code I put wrong code that distroy my it memory 
thanks alot

Comment: One more thing: use `++it` against `it++`. `it++` source code usually looks something like this: `iterator operator++(int i){ iterator temp = (*this); ++(*this); return temp; };`

Answer (score 0):

Think you have named the variable wrongly. Isnt the vector `m_vField`, whereas you have used`vField` in your loop.

Comment: This would still not explain why iterating over the vector in the code causes an access violation. Also, in such situations it is almost always a typo by the OP when asking the question (though not always). You should post this as a comment rather than an answer.

Comment: hmm.. true. Think the vector is declared inside a class. Just a doubt as he has written a separate function to push elements into the vector when it can be done directly also.